# Using wrap_content behavior and ellipsize if text too long

Tags: android, android-layout

I have three views on my layout *TextView1* *TextView2* and *ImageView*.

*TextView1* wraps content while *TextView2* aligned to end of *TextView1* 
[image]

I want to make *TextView1* ellipsize in the end when its content too long while width of *TextView1* *TextView2* *ImageView* together have filled all width of layout
[image]

I've tried a lot of options to make it in xml with LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, ConstraintLayout and none of them gave me desired result.

The closest one is

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/card_item_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="start"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_max="284dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/card_item_small_number"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/offset_6"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/offset_6"
            android:maxLines="1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/card_item_name"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/card_item_bank_logo"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:gravity="start"
            tools:text="**** 5555"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/card_item_bank_logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/offset_24"
            android:maxHeight="@dimen/offset_24"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_language"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Key thing here is in TextView1 attributes

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
app:layout_constraintWidth_max="284dp"
```

BUT that means I have to calculate *layout_constraintWidth_max* value at run time, because width of *TextView2* and *ImageView* are not fixed and depends on its values

Is there any way to make it ONLY in xml without 'magic' numbers ?

Comment: Have you tried setting constraint end for textview1 ? So tv1 endToStart of tv2 and remove max width

Comment: @P.Juni yes, I have. TextView1 in that case will match_constraint instead of wrap_contant.
That cause TextView1 to fill all free space

Answer (score -2):

try
android:layout_weight="1"
You can work around from that to fit your desire width on the views.
To make this work, user LinearLayout with horizontal orientation.